# Is there a function like "ismember" but more efficient?

Tags: matlab, set, performance

For example,A is the number set.b is elements.

I want to test whether the number in b is the element of the set A.

I know the matlab function "ismember" could do this ,but it's not fast enough when I use it one million times.

```
b=[1,2,9,100];
A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
tic;for ii=1:1e6,ismember(b,A);end;toc
Elapsed time is 45.714583 seconds.
```

I want to return [1,1,1,0],because 1,2,9 are in the set A,while 100 is not.

Do you know some functions like ismember or some ways more efficient than "ismember"?

Comment: Do you really need to use it 1 million times sequentially?

Comment: @ Dennis Jaheruddin I run it one million times just for testing the efficiency,not really want to run it one million times.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the mex version, i.e. `ismemberoneoutput`. The mex version is much faster.

```
b=[1,2,9,100];
A=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
tic;for ii=1:1e5,ismember(b,A);end;toc
%Elapsed time is 9.537219 seconds. On my pc

% A must be sorted!!! In this example it is already sorted,
% so no need for this here.
tic;for ii=1:1e5,builtin('_ismemberoneoutput',b,A);end;toc
%Elapsed time is 0.376556 seconds. On my pc
```

Comment: Thanks very much!By the way,where is the "_ismemberoneoutput"?"edit _ismemberoneoutput" could not find the function.How do you know the function?where is it?

Comment: @lihaitao Its buildin in matlab. What version u have? I tested it in 2013a?

Comment: @ Marcin I use R2013a.How do you know the function in matlab?How could I learn the builin  functions in matlab?

Comment: @lihaitao u can try other undocumented version, `ismembc(b,A)`. I learned about the buildin by checking the source of Matlab's ismember.m

Comment: For completeness: I think the primary reason for why it took over 9 seconds in this example is because `ismember` is not built-in, so that that test-loop cannot be JIT'ed. In other words, your test is non-general; the results are only valid for situations where `ismember` is used in a loop. Test again with really large `b` and `A`, and you'll see that both have comparable perforamnce. As you indicate, using the MEX variant is fragile and non-portable, because it creates a dependency on the specific MATLAB version. Use only for performance-critical parts, and document it well.

Comment: +1: there's also [`ismembc`](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/ismembc-undocumented-helper-function/).

Comment: @lihaitao: `_ismemberoneoutput` is supported for R2012a+ so you should have it I believe. But you can't run it like a normal function. You must call something like `builtin('_ismemberoneoutput',b,A)` as @Marcin showed because it is a mex C++ function. There are two other C++ mex functions listed in `ismember` if you type `edit ismember` and look at line 577+ or so. Finally, `ismembc` is an even older C mex function that you'll find.

Comment: removed in R2015a.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be possible to avoid, but one reason why your calculation is so slow is because you did not call `ismember` in a vectorized way.

Try this, it is easy and fast:

```
bigb = repmat(b,1e6,1);
ismember(bigb,A);
```

Comment: I run it one million times just for testing the efficiency,not really want to run it one million times.

Comment: @lihaitao true, a powerfull function like ismember is not very efficient for small scale examples. But my point is that unless you have run it millons of times, the time it takes to solve a small scale problem is probably not the most relevant measure of efficiency.