# Faster alternatives to ismember in Matlab when index positions are needed?

Tags: matlab

I am using `ismember` in Matlab to find the integers in the vector `A` not included in the vector `idx`. I would like to know whether there is something faster I could use.

In relation to my question, I have found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17714487/is-there-a-function-like-ismember-but-more-efficient) but it does not seem to work here because I need the index positions.

```
rng default;  %for reproducibility
A=randi([0 6],2097144,1); %2097144x1
idx=randi([0 6],4,1); %4x1

tic
% Find elements of idx not in A
[idx2,~,~]=unique(A);
[~,idx3]=ismember(idx,idx2);
idx4=idx(~idx3); 
toc

Elapsed time is 0.278835 seconds.
```

Comment: Is the range of values in your actual problem this small (0:6)? Have you profiled your code to see if it's `ismember` or `unique` that's taking the most time? Have you benchmarked any other approaches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`setdiff`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html) instead which will find the elements of the first input that are not present in the second input.

```
result = setdiff(idx, A);
```

For the size of input you've provided, I get a 35-fold improvement in execution time. This is likely due to the fact that you're using `unique(A)` which is going to be costly since it has to sort and process that huge array.

As a side-note, `tic` and `toc` are not a very accurate way of benchmarking code. Instead, you'll want to use `timeit`.

```
function comparison()
    A = randi([0, 6], 2097144, 1);
    B = randi([0, 6], 4, 1);

    disp(timeit(@()approach1(A, B)));
    disp(timeit(@()approach2(A, B)));
end

function idx4 = approach1(A, B)
    [idx2,~,~]=unique(A);
    [~,idx3]=ismember(B, idx2);
    idx4 = B(~idx3);
end

function res = approach2(A, B)
    res = setdiff(B, A);
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to use `setdiff`, see the [documentation](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/setdiff.html)

> `C = setdiff(A,B)` returns the data in `A` that is not in `B`, with no repetitions. `C` is in sorted order.

You want indices. Looking further down the docs we see

> `[C,ia] = setdiff(A,B)` also returns the index vector `ia`.

So try

```
A=randi([0 6],2097144,1); 
idx=randi([0 6],4,1); 

[~, idx2] = setdiff(A, idx);
```

Comment: What differentiates this from the existing answer?

Comment: @excaza Very little, Suever answered whilst I was writing mine so I didn't see, note there is only 3 minutes difference. Also his original answer didn't have a code example or documentation links so I left mine standing in case it was helpful.

Comment: His original question [did have a documentation link and code](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/42955618/1)

Comment: @excaza As I say, we answered at the same time, my reflex isn't to delete a valid answer because I see someone else posted one too